# IIS 6.0 Disable Head Request

Tags: iis-6, request, head

How do I disable HEAD request under IIS 6.0 other than using URLScan Tool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For one particular extension, or all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for just one or a few extensions, see http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/4c840252-fab7-427e-a197-7facb6649106.mspx?mfr=true

In the same tab, you can specify the verbs.